# Convert createReducer to switch case reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, reduce

Currently I am using createReducer (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createreducer), but now I am looking forward to convert it into switch case reducer (https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/refactoring-reducer-example).
I've tried to convert it, but somehow things are going wrong and I am not sure what's the correct way to handle nested object through switch case reducer

My code with createReducer

```
export let sampleReducer = createReducer(initialState, {

  [ACTIONS.ADD_USER]: (state, action) => {
    if (state.user[action.info]) {
      state.user[action.info].details = action.details;
    }
  }
});

export default sampleReducer;
```

Above code is working fine, but when i convert it into switch case, I am not getting the expected response.

New code

```
export const sampleReducer = (
  state: sampleState = initialState,
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case ACTIONS.ADD_USER:
      if (state.user[action.info]) {
        return {
          ...state
          user: {
            [action.info]: {
              details: action.details
            }

          },
        };
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default sampleReducer;
```

Please let me know if new way of writing reducer is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

**Please don't do this!**  We want people to use RTK's APIs, and *not* switch-case functions!

In fact, you shouldn't even be using `createReducer` in most cases.  The "right" answer here is to use [RTK's `createSlice` API](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#using-createslice), which will generate the action creators and action types for you:

```js
const sampleSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'sample'
  initialState, 
  reducers: {
    userAdded: (state, action) => {
      if (state.user[action.info]) {
        state.user[action.info].details = action.details;
      }
    }
  }
});

export const { userAdded } = sampleSlice.actions;
export default sampleSlice.reducer;
```

Some of our docs pages are older and haven't been updated to show the latest APIs and patterns, but you *should* be using RTK for everything.

Additionally, the *concepts* shown in pages like the "Structuring Reducers" section are valid no matter how you actually write the code.

Comment: that's a great suggestion @markerikson. I'll definitely try it out, but at this point, would it be possible for you to let me what's wrong I am doing in my code while using switch case. I am not sure if I am syntactically correct here or not

Comment: The _syntax_ looks okay. I think the issue may be with the `if(state.user[action.info])` part in the first place, because if you're _adding_ a user, there probably won't be an entry for that key yet anyway.  Can't say for sure without seeing the rest of the state structure for this reducer.

Comment: Also, you have an accidental fallthrough to the next reducer case (in this case the default) there since not all code paths of the case `return` something. In this case it's probably fine but if you had more cases it would be a bug.
But generally, really, please don't do it. We as Redux maintainers are recommending `createSlice` over switch-case reducers since 2019.